# Magento ignores extra URL parameters set

Tags: magento, query-string

I am trying to open a Magento store link from an external site. While opening the store link I need to send some information using the query string parameters. 
So I open a link (through php code) such as: 
http://magentostore.com/myproduct.html?id=3434&user=445

However the Magento store link ignores the query string parameters and reloads the page as:
magentostore.com/myproduct.html

I checked in Firebug and can see that there was a redirect to the Magento store without the query string parameters. Is there a way to override this behavior and let Magento load with the query string parameters?
What setting can I do in the Magento store to let it allow using the query string parameters?
Is there any other way of sending some more information to the Magento store page?

Is there a way to find out if its Magento doing this and not the server?

Thanks

Comment: Magento is receiving the queries on the first request but redirects to the URL it has in the URL Rewrite list. This is probably for SEO reasons. Whatever code you have that needs those values should store them in a session variable before the redirect happens.

Comment: As a side note, please don't do anything that would override Magento's security measures by adding ?user=445 to the query string.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. We are trying to talk to the Magento store via an external site. Basically when a particular Magento store page loads we want it to know that it is coming from our known external site and also who is sending it. This is achieved via the query string parameter (uid). We need this for only one page. We have some javascript on the Magento page that will read the query string and then create some cookies for tracking. Is there any other way of achieving this? Can we turn off the query string sanitization for one page only? This is very critical ..

Comment: Thanks @clockworkgeek. I researched for the URL rewrites and looks like there was a URL redirect for the product link! I have removed it and have my scenario working. However would be great to know if there is anything that can be done to make sure the Magento code does not do any query string parameter sanitization. Thanks a lot..

Comment: @clockworkgeek: Maybe you could copy your comment as an answer since it looks like it answered the original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento is receiving the queries on the first request but redirects to the URL it has in the URL Rewrite list. This is probably for SEO reasons. Whatever code you have that needs those values should store them in a session variable before the redirect happens.

**deveffort says:**
I researched for the URL rewrites and looks like there was a URL redirect for the product link! I have removed it and have my scenario working. However would be great to know if there is anything that can be done to make sure the Magento code does not do any query string parameter sanitization. Thanks a lot..

**clockworkgeek says:**
I fear removing that rewrite is temporary. It will replace itself on the next product re-index or perhaps when the product is saved. Since you only want to set some cookies it needn't be done by javascript, that is less reliable anyway.
Instead, create an observer to watch for an event of `catalog_controller_product_view`. Have the observer check for the query parameters, and if the correct one exists, set the cookie. Also it might try checking the referrer URL matches what you expect of it, that might make spoofing the values a little harder.

Comment: Thanks.. will check into magento event hooks. Any specific reason why setting the cookies is unreliable via js?

Comment: Because js isn't always enabled, or is enabled but an earlier error on the page stops execution. Those are rare cases but I've grown used to doing as much as possible on the server where I can retain control and backing everything up with another process too.